# How to get voice amplitude from pocketsphinx

Tags: cmusphinx, pocketsphinx, pocketsphinx-android

I am using pocketsphinx to recognize words in android application when someone speak. I want to implement functionality to return a max amplitude of a voice which pocketsphinx record. If i speak any word i need to get a sound level in return(Either word recognize or not from decoder). 
What i have done: I look into the code of pocketsphinx-->SpeechRecognizer currently commented in source file:

```
 /*              while (!interrupted()
                && ((timeoutSamples == NO_TIMEOUT) || (remainingSamples > 0))) {
            int nread = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

            if (-1 == nread) {
                throw new RuntimeException("error reading audio buffer");
            } else if (nread > 0) {
                decoder.processRaw(buffer, nread, false, false);

                int max = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < nread; i++) {
                    max = Math.max(max, Math.abs(buffer[i]));
                }....
```

I seems to be that this max value is calculating from a buffer How i can calculate this from complete recording. Can someone give me hint?

Answer (score 0):

That would be it, just make max a field of SpeechRecognizer class and do not initialize it every time, but only on start recognition:

```
class SpeechRecognizer() {

     double maxLevel;

     void startRecognition() {
         maxLevel = 0.0;
     }

     ....         
        @Override
        public void run() {
                decoder.processRaw(buffer, nread, false, false);

                double level = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < nread; i++) {
                    level += buffer[i] * buffer[i];
                }
                level = sqrt(level / nread);
                if (maxLevel < level)
                    maxLevel = level
      ....

}
```

Here I recommend you to use root mean square (RMS) instead of simply max because it is more stable estimate for a maximum amplitude, it is resistant to simple bursts of amplitude like clicks.

It is also a good idea to return RMS from every buffer with the result and update maxLevel inside the application, not within recognizer.

Comment: This is how i used to calculate a noise level from speech recognizer class and send back to my service (unable to formate below code):                             double sum = 0, amplitudeDb = 0;
                     for (int i = 0; i < nread; i++) {
                        sum += buffer[i] * buffer[i];
                    }
                    if (nread > 0) {
                        final double amplitude = sum / nread;
                        amplitudeDb = (int) Math.sqrt(amplitude);
                    }
                    mainHandler.post(new AmplitudeEvent(amplitudeDb));